# ¿como se podra realizar un menu fijo adaptable a difirentes dispositivos?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

como podre dejar el menú fijo, que cuando este bajando, el menú siga hay fijo para el usuario, y sea adaptable teléfonos móviles, lo eh intentado pero me desaparece el menu.
acá esta el html, con cual esta el menu, no se si hay alguna manera de realizarlo solo con html, con ayuda de bootstrap 5, ignorando css.? evitando poner mas código, es posible realizar esa accion a cortar codigo, porque puede que con css me quede más amplio, no se si me podrian ayudar con este problema, o tips para llegar a una solucion correcta :(

Se agradece la ayudita:(

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="main_navbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hola</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            >
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                  href="#"
                  role="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                >
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a
                      class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                      href="#"
                      role="button"
                      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    >
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                          >Something else here</a
                        >
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a
              class="nav-link disabled"
              href="#"
              tabindex="-1"
              aria-disabled="true"
              >Disabled</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input
            class="form-control me-2"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: ¿no te sale el botón hamburguesa cuando se hace más pequeño?  Es lo que le estás diciendo al poner el <button> con la `class="navbar-toggler"` y los collapse.  O te refieres a un [sticky](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#sticky-top) o [fixed-top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#fixed-top)?

Comment: el menu de hamburguesa sale, pero cuando me despliego en el index hacia abajo el menu no queda fijo, para que sea mas facil al momento de moverse en menu

Comment: Mira los otros enlaces que he puesto en mi otro comentario, a ver si te sirve

Comment: seria como un fixed-top

Comment: cual me ayudaria con dejar fijo el menu

Comment: si usas fixed-top debes ponerle un padding al body creo (o quizás al nav), para que quede bien.  [En este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124805/10382744) lo explican

Comment: añadir css, ir viendo como va

Comment: Revisa el enlace que acabo de poner en mi anterior comentario (a veces los escribo a cachos y no se ven si no refrescas la página, sorry)

Comment: hay veo la pagina, sale con los css , voy entendiendo como puede ser

Comment: comento como me va.. dsp

Comment: ok, suerte!  (yo ya cierro por hoy, pero déjalo dicho o postea tu mismo la respuesta con lo que te haya funcionado)  Saludos

Comment: dale pa gracias, por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

solucion propuesta, agregar una div class

```
<div class="fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="main_navbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">hola</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            >
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                  href="#"
                  role="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                >
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a
                      class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                      href="#"
                      role="button"
                      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    >
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                          >Something else here</a
                        >
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a
              class="nav-link disabled"
              href="#"
              tabindex="-1"
              aria-disabled="true"
              >Disabled</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input
            class="form-control me-2"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

mas css, para no dejar un espacio en blanco entre el menu y el cuerpo

```
   body { padding-top:60px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A mí parecer sería mucho mejor agregarle una sola clase adicional al `nav`:

**sticky-top**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark">
```

Y eso sería todo.
Aunque Bootstrap no tiene ejemplo de `sticky-top` de nav, sí tiene esa clase y es mejor que `fixed-top` (que sí tiene un ejemplo)

Y los [ejemplos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbars/) de Bootstrap son muy buenos — por si acaso.

Y la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/) está completo.